# How to proceed if equals was overridden but not hashCode?

Tags: java, hashcode

I've come across some third-party code that overrides equals() but not hashCode().  Would I be right in thinking that as long as I do not use these objects as Map keys, this is harmless?

I could of course add the override for hashCode (in several objects) but then I would be creating more work for myself every time I receive an upgrade.

Comment: Is it an open source project? If yes, consider to do yourself and everyone else that uses the third-party library a big favor by submitting the missing missing hashCode() method(s) if you decide to implement them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than Map you need to check :

1. if you are using instance of this class in your ORM, more info [at](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode), on the hashcode implementation you can use [Apache's HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html).
2. Comparator, Comparable on this class cannot use hashcode to check for comparison.
3. [Pragmatic Concept](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/1006)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can assume that it's harmless.  HashMap will be using hashCode.

I'd find another library.  If they can't override equals and hashCode properly, what else are they doing wrong?

Comment: "as I do not use these objects as Map keys" covers your "HashMap will be using hashCode" bit, I think.

Comment: @Jon, is there nothing to be said that this is such poor practice that it indeed raises concerns over the quality of the rest of the library?

Comment: @KirkWoll: Yes, I agree with that part of the answer. I was disagreeing with the first part.

Comment: Unfortunately there is probably no cost effective alternative and the average user is not really the complaining type.  (It creates barriers to entry if quality is iffy and it creates consulting jobs.)  I was hoping for tips on what to watch for besides Map/HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

If the objects do not extend another class (so they inherit from Object) then their hashCode is a function of their object reference. That means if you use them as the key in a HashMap (or as an element of a HashSet), you can only expect to find them if you use the exact same instance of the object to do the look up.

The "contract" is that if two objects are equal then they must have the same hashCode, however your analysis is correct - hashCode only matters in the collections API (HashSet, HashMap, etc.). You should know how you will be using the API so if you know you will not be using the hashCode, and you do not expose this objects of the API in your public API, then there is no problem.